# How to create a scale from a colored DEM?

Tags: dem, scale, usgs

I am trying to create a scale from this image

[image]
<sub><sub>[image source](https://www1.udel.edu/johnmack/data_library/usa_dem.png)</sub></sub>

How would I be able to create a colored scale corresponding to the image height exactly, as I do not have any programs that I can download DEM data from the USGS site and make a DEM myself.

Comment: You can't without knowledge of how the elevations were mapped to colours. The conversion to PNG is lossy. What are you really trying to do, and why can't you use a web browser which is all you really need to download from USGS?

Comment: What software are you working with?

Comment: Arcmap is the software

Comment: Wel,l I downloaded the map package from the site that I found this DEM and imported into ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

You could try building a color ramp using an online tool. You would have to try and match the colors to what is showing on your map.

For example:
http://www.zonums.com/online/color_ramp/

Another thing I might try: Find a sample map on the ESRI developer network that lets you dynamically symbolize raster data. I am pretty sure that exact symbology set would be an option. You might be able to take a screen capture and manually adjust the values.